# How can I change the showDateTimePicker() into 12 hour format?

Tags: flutter

I want the time change into 12 hours format. Here's my code:

```
            TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(
                context,
                showTitleActions: true,
                onConfirm: widget.onChangeDateSched,
                locale: LocaleType.en,
              );
            },
```

Comment: what are you using for `DatePicker`?

Comment: i'm using it to collect data for date and time in setting an alarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with this package [flutter_datetime_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker)

```
TextButton(
        child: Text("Time Pick"),
        onPressed: ()
        {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          DatePicker.showTime12hPicker(
            context,
            showTitleActions: true,

            locale: LocaleType.en,
          );
        }
    )
```

output:

[image]

For both date and time use this package [date_time_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/date_time_picker) and initialize the date formatting

```
initializeDateFormatting('en');
TextButton(
          child: DateTimePicker(
            locale: Locale('en'),
            type: DateTimePickerType.dateTimeSeparate,
            dateMask: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            initialValue: DateTime.now().toString(),
            firstDate: DateTime(2000),
            lastDate: DateTime.now(),
            icon: Icon(Icons.event),
            use24HourFormat: false,
            dateLabelText: 'Date',
            timeLabelText: "Hour",
            onChanged: (val) {
              print(val);

            },
          ),
      )
```

output:
[image]

Comment: i need to use showDateTimePIcker() to get the date too

Comment: if you want both you can try with the dateTimePicker Package https://pub.dev/packages/date_time_picker

Comment: @AdrianAlejo please have a look, i updated my answer with both date and time

Answer (score 1):

you may use

```
final format = DateFormat("HH:mm");
```

to sort out your issue..

Answer (score 0):

```
                DatePicker.showTime12hPicker(
                  context,
                  showTitleActions: true,
                  locale: LocaleType.en,
                  currentTime: DateTime.now()
                );
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.